# Determine the bandwidth of a webpage

Tags: bandwidth

I am trying to find the bandwidth of a webpage.

I have tried, but I only get about server or for an application.

The webpage has chat server, flash player.

Comment: share details to what you have tried

Comment: Press F12 or Ctrl+Maj+I to open your developer tools.  Go the "network" tab. Watch the page usage of network requests and their size/time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the dev console (F12) and network tab or request

Also, you have a summary with bandwidth in real time

- On Firefox:

[image]

- On Chorme:

[image]

Comment: I did this but there is no option available for bandwidth except size and time.

Comment: That's all you need, I completed my answer